# How to disable messages from of HTML validation but keep validation enabled

Tags: html, validation

I need to disable **only the error message** of HTML Validation; the actual validation should still be there. User won't submitted the form without filling text field. Even if the user does not fill in a required text field, I don't want to display any message like "Please fill out this field".

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `novalidate` attribute to skip validation from HTML and then add validation code on javascript - on submit event.

HTML:

```
<form novalidate>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" required>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    //check validations and submit through AJAX
    return false;
});
```